# Comic with Obi-Wan and Quinlan Vos

Tags: story-identification, star-wars

I'm looking for a comic with young Obi-Wan and Quinlan Vos, I think when they're Padawans.  I've only seen some of the panels from this.  They're meditating by a river, Quinlan falls in and Obi-Wan saves him.  Where is this from?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is *[Star Wars Republic #69](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Republic_69)*

It features Padawan Obi-Wan and Quinlan Vos meditating by a river into which they fall.

[image]